# BatchGetSymbols -> GetSP500Stocks() -> Error: Table has inconsistent number of columns. Do you want fill = TRUE?

Tags: r, finance

I've been working with the R package BatchGetSymbols and it normally works quite nice.  Today my workflow is failing on the GetSP500Stocks() function with the message "Error: Table has inconsistent number of columns. Do you want fill = TRUE?".

Is anyone else seeing this as of today?

```
install.packages("BatchGetSymbols")

library(BatchGetSymbols)

df.SP500 <- GetSP500Stocks()
```

> GetSP500Stocks()
>   Error: Table has inconsistent number of columns. Do you want fill = TRUE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author here. This is an issue with the HTML table in wikipedia. I just fixed it in github and it should go to CRAN soon. Try this:

```
devtools::install_github('msperlin/BatchGetSymbols')

library(BatchGetSymbols)

df.SP500 <- GetSP500Stocks()
```

Btw, next time, post an issue in [github](https://github.com/msperlin/BatchGetSymbols/issues) and I'll fix it.

Best,